# ng-bind-html is not able to bind text and image url together

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am trying to use some string and a image together in ng-bind-html tag in AngularJS but it is giving error so far what i did is

```
<div class="row">
    <span data-ng-bind-html="question"></span>
</div>
```

If only string value is coming or only image url is coming then it works fine but when string + image url both are coming it does not display anything and it thrown error(404) can not find resource.

This value is coming from DB which will assign to question variable

"This is Instruction for below question"

http://localhost:8080/OnlineExam/static/css/question_images/ tid_27-8-16_10AM_qno_25.png

Comment: What you mean string + image ?

Comment: Means Data Should be like "Look into below image and answer the question based on that image " 
 http://www.example.com/images/question1.png       here Neither it shows image nor the text but if if i am writing only  http://www.example.com/images/question1.png Image shows perfectly

Comment: sorry permission denied

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("exApp",["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce){
$scope.image = $sce.trustAsHtml('<img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/s6rmeo.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<span ng-bind-html="image"></span>
</div>
</body>
```